# Loading while moving from activity to another in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, progress-bar, loading

I have build an Android application does every thing I want but my last problem is when I click a button to move to another activity, the app show me white page for a while and then show the target page, I am wondering how to fill this gap with loading or progress, something founded in all familiar mobile applications.

Comment: first of all check what is causing delay in your acitivity.

Comment: if it is an API call then you should show progress dialogue before starting API call and then close it on Completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a progress bar to the activity. So once the content loads you can just set the visibility to gone. Try add this into your activities xml

```
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/myprogressbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```